# Intereactive Line graph

Tags: vba, graph

Does anyone know if it is possible to create an interactive line graph (I use the term interactive because, am not sure of the actual technical term) in VBA? Basically, when the cursor is run over the line and it reads the values. Such as:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=FTSE100&form=PRDLC1&src=IE11TR&pc=DCTE

I am not even sure if its possible in VBA. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: While your above link is merely a search for a certain term and some search engine I guess I understand what you are looking for. Most Excel charts offer this functionality naturally. But if you wish to change / refine that with VBA then you're out of luck. For that you would need some kind of Excel event to capture. Yet, there is no such event in Excel.

Comment: Thanks very much Ralph

Comment: In excel if you hover over a line marker it will tell you the value.